# Force Bootstrap collapse mobile menu to move down and not up?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap (3.2.0) for a new website. I have added a button like this:

```
<button id="menu-mobile" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Menu
</button>
```

And on another place this collapse:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="">
     <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="products"><span>Products</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="some"><span>Some</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>

<script>    
$("#navbar-collapse-1 ul").first().addClass('nav navbar-nav navbar-right').attr('id', '');  
</script> 
</div>
```

This is all added into this nav:

```
<nav id="top-navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
...
</nav>
```

Now the collapse starts from bottom and **folds upwards**. But there is not enough space, so one menu item is hidden.

**How can I force it to open from the top and downwards, so I can show all menu items?**

I want to keep it as now: The collapse is overlaying the other content. That is good. I just want to get it to move down in stead of moving up.

SOLUTION: Thanks to @Stephan Weinhold for the link below
In my case it was in this CSS:

```
div#navbar-collapse-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;   <-- here
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 790px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

I simply edited this to top:0px;

```
div#navbar-collapse-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;   <-- changed
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 790px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That set me on right course. I add the answer above :-)

Comment: How come this is set as a duplicate question? In my opinion it is not. This is a question about how to redirect the direction of the collapse (move up versus down). It is not a question about pushing other content.